# Enhanced SQL Replace function - able to handle a variable part

Tags: mysql, sql, variables, replace

I would like to update thousands records in my SQL dB.

my **post_content** from **my_table** is like:

> blablabla htt*://vimeo.com/**12345678** blablabla

or

> blablabla htt*://vimeo.com/**12345678** blablabla htt*://vimeo.com/**12345678** (blablabla)

and I would like to replace the

> htt*://vimeo.com/**12345678**

by

`<iframe src="htt*://player.vimeo.com/video/12345678?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen allowFullScreen></iframe>`

The problem is that 12345678 is different on each post...and I have to replace code before this number and add code after this number.

Replace code before the number is easy, but after, I don't know how to do it? How to say to the replace function: find htt*://vimeo/12345678 and point after the numbers and add "?title=0&a...< /iframe>.

Any idea?

Comment: What SQL version?  mySQL?   Microsoft SQL 2005, MS SQL 2008, Oracle?

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea. An insult to normalisation. Next step is probably putting VB-script into a database row.

Comment: He writes "my SQL dB" in the first line. I added a tag.

Comment: The video embedding methods change every now and then. Why not just store the ID and leave the rendering to your PHP/ASP script?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood it good, I suppose you can create your own function that takes some variables and inside it do some replacing etc.

```
CREATE FUNCTION MyReplace (Link nvarchar(4000), myVar nvarchar(500))
RETURNS nvarchar
DECLARE Result nvarchar(4000)
--create some replacing logic here, call REPLACE function etc: 
--Result=...
RETURN Result
```

Later, call this function in your query, passing two parameters - original link and your variable.

However, I'm not sure is it a good practice, as was mentioned above.